# Start sh in a specified directory from inittab

Tags: shell, busybox, sysvinit, ash

I am currently working on an embedded Linux system. For it to be similar to our other products I need to have it start a shell in a specified directory on boot, accessible using the serial port.

For that I have this line in the inittab-script:

```
::respawn:-/bin/sh
```

This is working so far, only that the shell starts up with a pwd of /, instead of /mnt/flash.

The only way I can come up with is to have it not start /bin/sh but instead a script like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /mnt/flash
/bin/sh
```

Is there a way to do that in-line in the inittab without a second script?

Edit: I need this to be a login script. This is what the `-` before the `/bin/sh` signifies. If I just run `::respawn:/bin/sh -c "cd /mnt/flash;exec /bin/sh"` it does change the folder as expected, but I don't get a login shell which causes other problems.

If I run it with `::respawn:-/bin/sh -c "cd /mnt/flash;exec /bin/sh` I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: exec: line 1: -/bin/sh: not found
```

Comment: End your script with `exec /bin/sh` instead of just `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give the shell some arguments, so that it starts slightly differently. eg.

```
/bin/sh -c "cd /mnt/flash;exec /bin/sh"
```

Starting with `-c` which will execute commands in following string.

First command is the directory change, followed by `exec` which will start a new shell (in the same process) which is now starting in your desired directory.

Update:

If busybox shell is being used, there is a problem starting a login shell since busybox does not accept the `-l` option. Use the dot `.` command to source commands from your profile(s) before you do the `exec` eg

```
/bin/sh -c "cd /mnt/flash;. /etc/profile;exec /bin/sh"
```

Comment: This almost works for me. The problem is I need a login shell. If I run this without the - at the beginning it works, but it's not a login shell which causes new problems. If I run it like this: `::respawn:-/bin/sh -c "cd /mnt/flash;exec /bin/sh"` I get this error: `/bin/sh: exec: line1: -/bin/sh: not found`

Comment: does your shell accept the `-l` or `--login` option this will make it a login shell. read `man sh` for your system, you haven't specified which shell you are running.

Comment: I tried that, but I get the same result as without the `-l` and without the `-` in the beginning. I am running busybox sh.

Comment: This was particularly helpful for me, where the use case was starting an interactive shell inside a docker container without having to manually `cd` into a long path every time.